# How to get the count of records returned by teradata sql griup by query

Tags: group-by, teradata, rowcount, select-query

I have a condition where I need to check number of rows returned by select query in Teradata.

My query looks like below

```
select 
PDate ,Risk ,BName ,BNumber ,
ONumber ,OnNumber ,ID_CD ,Entity ,
AU ,RType, count (*) 
from Load_one.import_test
group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
having count (*) > 1;
```

So I would like to know the count of rows it returns. I tried something like below

```
Select Count(*)
From    ( select 
PDate ,Risk ,BName ,BNumber ,
ONumber ,OnNumber ,ID_CD ,Entity ,
AU ,RType, count (*) 
from Load_one.import_test
group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
having count (*) > 1;
)  as temp
```

It returning an error: select failed 3707 expected something like an 'EXCEPT' keyword or an 'UNION' keyword or a 'MINUS' keyword between an integer and ;

Please help me.

Comment: Just remove the semicolon after `having count(*) > 1`, that is all.

Comment: Why do you nee the count as a seperate request? The very first information returned by Teradata is the number of rows in the result set (Teradata starts retunrning the 1st row of an answer set after it's *fully* created).

Comment: I would like to use the count returned by the query inside to start a job. @dnoeth